# I want to Understand Android Log

Tags: android, android-logcat

is any one know what is the meaning this LOG test 
it display every time when i do any operation in my APP 
TEXT

```
09-06 17:41:30.194: D/dalvikvm(4900): GC_CONCURRENT freed 440K, 49% free 3317K/6471K, external 0K/512K, paused 4ms+7ms
```

dos it related to memory allocation ?

Comment: This is a memory log, [check out this link for more information](https://sites.google.com/site/pyximanew/blog/androidunderstandingddmslogcatmemoryoutputmessages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GC_CONCURRENT

Means that Garbage Collection happens in a parallel manner. Without affecting any performance.

> freed 440K

This particular cycle of GC has freed 440k memory.

> free 3317K/6471K

Available and total Heap Memory Details.

> external 0K/512K

External Memory available for your app(other than heap).

> 4ms+7ms

4ms at the beginning of GC was paused and at the end 7ms was consumed by GC.

That is, during this GC, all your activities were suspended for a total of 11ms , 4ms at the beginning and 7ms at the end.

For more info on this, please watch this video. He explains this very clearly.

[Patrick Dubroy Memory Management](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&ei=hJZIULLzKYWIrAeIrICQBA&usg=AFQjCNEfUDM7yYu-Cb6hrLjEOm5xk29LkA)

Comment: yes.. , my PM say that This app has serious memory leak problem, please terminate unused Activity /View. have u any idea to find it..(is this Log help me to find it).

Comment: Log is just a key. Please watch the whole video. It has everything you are looking for. He explains about MAT and stuffs to be done for memory leak. Please do watch the entire video. Man you will love it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. It shows that garbage colector was fired ( which happens on regular basis) and it could reclaim 440K of memory.  Whether it is a lot or not depends on your application,   but less is better.  Rule of thumb is to avoid memory allocation  whenever possible.